# PowerShell - Send-MailMessage with AWS SES - Intermittent

Tags: powershell, smtp, amazon-ses

I've been using the below script to send email and sometimes it works, sometimes it does not. I'm not sure exactly why it is intermittent and with this error:

"**ERROR: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: Authentication required**"

This is the script I'm using:

```
$AWS_ACCESS_KEY = "KEYYYYYYYYYY"
$AWS_SECRET_KEY = "SECRET_KEYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
$SECURE_KEY = $(ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -String $AWS_SECRET_KEY -Force)
$creds = $(New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($AWS_ACCESS_KEY, $SECURE_KEY))

$smtp = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
$from = "noreply@domain.com"
$to = "to_you@domain.com"
$bcc = "its_me@domain.com"
$subject = "Hello There"
$body = "Hey Friend!<br><br>"
$body += "Body<br><br>"
$body += "Regards,<br>"
$body += "Bye<br>"

#Sending email
Sleep 2
Send-MailMessage -From $from -To $to -Bcc $bcc -Subject $subject -Body $body -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $smtp -Credential $creds -UseSsl -Port 587
```

What could be the issue? Has anyone seen this before? Any log in AWS console that I could look at?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I'm getting the same - only noticed recently some emails weren't sending. All are going to the same support email address to our own domain. Most work fine and some fail. I'd switch to something else but don't currently have access to the DNS.

Comment: Oh yeah our case at that time was because I was using the old AWS encryption mechanism, so just had to create a new key (that is already using the new format) and all set. But I know this week AWS us-east was having some issues, so not sure which one is your issue.

Comment: Thanks. No errors since then but this only handles a dozen emails a day. This is pretty much the only AWS service I use so my interpretation was 'email isn't working' as opposed to 'AWS isn't working'. The key I used was about 8 years old - it still worked just not every time.

Comment: right, my issue was like that... one email worked, other one too, next one no... intermittent and after using a very fresh new key it is just flowing as a charm.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced a similar issue managed to resolve with the below codes.

```
    $smtpServer = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" 
$smtpPort = 587  
$username = "************"
$password = "***********************"  
$from = "alerts@test.com"
$to = "recipient@domain.com"
$subject = "Amazon SES Test Email"
$body = "Body Amazon SES Test Email"
$cc = "xyz@domain.com"
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer, $smtpPort)
$smtp.EnableSsl = $true 
$smtp.Credentials = new-object Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password)
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$msg.From = $from
$msg.To.Add($to)
$msg.CC.Add($cc)
$msg.Subject = $subject
$smtp.Send($msg)
$msg.Body = $body
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to this bug is that it is intermittent, it does not happen all the time. The exact response from the SMTP server (SES) gives a more detailed response;

> 535 Signature Version 2 is deprecated for use with SES from March 26,
> 2021. From that date on, we are progressively rejecting such requests. To resolve the issue, you must migrate to Signature Version 4. If you
> created your SMTP credentials in the SES Console, please create new
> credentials and replace the former ones. If you are deriving Signature
> Version 2 credentials from a IAM user, please start using the
> Signature Version 4 algorithm:
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html

Which in short, means that you should re-generate a new AWS SES username / password pair, and stop using credenials from prior to 2021.